# React - getDerivedStateFromProps - field values will load the props but won't change

Tags: reactjs

I am getting a warning in the console that old lifecycle function componentWillReceiveProps will be discontinued soon. It is to be replaced with getDerivedStateFromProps.
I have redux connected to the component and action which fetches data with request to the API. I had a state set up on the component and once I received props I have updated the state and display the data in the input fields. On input fields, I had onChange called to change the state which changed the value in the fields.

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchStationId, updateStation } from '../../actions/station';
import { STATION } from '../../actions/types';
import TemplatePage from '../templates/TemplatePage';
import Card from '../partials/Card';
import Msg from '../partials/Msg';
import Preloader from '../partials/Preloader';

class StationsEdit extends Component {

  state = {
    custom_id: '',
    phone: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchStationId({ id: parseInt(this.props.match.params.id, 10)})
  }


  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.station.station !== undefined) {
      let { custom_id, phone } = nextProps.station.station;
      this.setState({
        custom_id: custom_id === null ? custom_id = '' : custom_id,
        phone: phone === null ? phone = '' : phone,
      });
    }
  }






  handleOnSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.custom_id === '') {
      return this.props.pushStationMessage({ type: STATION.PUSH_MESSAGE, "status" : "error", "message": [{ msg: "Custom ID is missing" }], fields: [ 'custom_id' ] });
    }
    return this.props.updateStation({ station: { custom_id: this.state.custom_id, phone: this.state.phone } })
    .then(() => {
      if(this.props.station.status !== 'error') {
        this.props.history.push('/stations');
      }
    })
  }

  get msg() {
    if(this.props.station.station !== '') {
      return <Msg msg={this.props.station} />
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {

    const { station, status } = this.props.station;
    const { custom_id, phone } = this.state;

    console.log('state', this.state)

    return (
      <TemplatePage>

        { /*this.msg*/ }
        { !station && status !== 'error' && <Preloader class='preloader preloader--centered' /> }


        <Card title='Edit Station' buttonBack={true} buttonLink='/stations' padding='large'>

          <form className="form">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="custom_id">
                Station ID
              </label>
              <input 
                type="text" 
                name="custom_id"
                id="custom_id" 
                value={custom_id}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ custom_id: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="phone">
                Station phone
              </label>
              <input 
                type="text" 
                name="phone"
                id="phone" 
                value={phone}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ phone: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input 
                type="submit" 
                value="Update station" 
                className="btn btn--primary card__footer--btn-left"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
          </Card>

      </TemplatePage>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  ({ station }) => ({ station }),
  { fetchStationId, updateStation }
)(StationsEdit);
```

That all worked fantastically well! Now I am reading that componentWillReceiveProps is going away and this is actually antipattern. Fine. However, swapping this for getDerivedStateFfromProps turns to be a more painful matter. I managed to change the componentWillReceiveProps for the getDerviedStateFromProps which updates the inputs as it used to do, however now trying to change the value in the fields will get overridden each time with the props. In effect no matter what I type to any of the fields they won't change the value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchStationId, updateStation } from '../../actions/station';
import { STATION } from '../../actions/types';
import TemplatePage from '../templates/TemplatePage';
import Card from '../partials/Card';
import Msg from '../partials/Msg';
import Preloader from '../partials/Preloader';

class StationsEdit extends Component {

  state = {
    custom_id: '',
    phone: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchStationId({ id: parseInt(this.props.match.params.id, 10)})
  }



  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    console.log('nextProps',nextProps.station.station)
    console.log('prevState', prevState)
    if (prevState !== nextProps.station.station) {
      return {
        ...nextProps.station.station
      };
    }
    return null;
  }





  handleOnSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.custom_id === '') {
      return this.props.pushStationMessage({ type: STATION.PUSH_MESSAGE, "status" : "error", "message": [{ msg: "Custom ID is missing" }], fields: [ 'custom_id' ] });
    }
    return this.props.updateStation({ station: { custom_id: this.state.custom_id, phone: this.state.phone } })
    .then(() => {
      if(this.props.station.status !== 'error') {
        this.props.history.push('/stations');
      }
    })
  }

  get msg() {
    if(this.props.station.station !== '') {
      return <Msg msg={this.props.station} />
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {

    const { station, status } = this.props.station;
    const { custom_id, phone } = this.state;

    console.log('state', this.state)

    return (
      <TemplatePage>

        { /*this.msg*/ }
        { !station && status !== 'error' && <Preloader class='preloader preloader--centered' /> }


        <Card title='Edit Station' buttonBack={true} buttonLink='/stations' padding='large'>

          <form className="form">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="custom_id">
                Station ID
              </label>
              <input 
                type="text" 
                name="custom_id"
                id="custom_id" 
                value={custom_id}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ custom_id: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="phone">
                Station phone
              </label>
              <input 
                type="text" 
                name="phone"
                id="phone" 
                value={phone}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ phone: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input 
                type="submit" 
                value="Update station" 
                className="btn btn--primary card__footer--btn-left"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
          </Card>

      </TemplatePage>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  ({ station }) => ({ station }),
  { fetchStationId, updateStation }
)(StationsEdit);
```

Can anyone point me the right direction? What am I missing here? I need the original value from the DB to be loaded only once and then be editable by users (this is edit form). Thank you for your valuable insights and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition will always return `true` because you are comparing 2 objects. In JS, the "===" and "!==" operators are not deep.

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState !== nextProps.station.station) { // Always return true
    return {
      ...nextProps.station.station
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

You can check some libraries for that:

- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual
- https://ramdajs.com/docs/#equals
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal

### **Second solution**

Check each property of your state:

```js
if (prevState.custom_id !== nextProps.station.station.custom_id || ... ) {
  return {
    ...nextProps.station.station
  }
}
```

### **Third solution**

Did you try with `componentDidUpdate` instead ?

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { station } = this.props;

  if (!deepEqual(station, prevProps.station)) {
    this.setState({ ...station })
  }
}
```